# How to Automate/Get AWS environment variables value thru API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Hello is there's a way to automate/get this value from AWS? Currently I'm doing this manually but I'm planning to automate this. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

These are the values I'll like to get the values

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

AWS_SESSION_TOKEN

FYI: By clicking Command line or programmatic it will prompt this interface.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, your question does not make much sense. To be able to programmatically interact with AWS you already have to have your credentials setup. So its not possible to get them programmatically if you do not have credentials already setup up.

Comment: I have the access but I want to automate that, but my concern here is the KeyId, Access Key and Token are dynamic this keeps on changing. so I'm looking for a way to find to generate this thru API so I could pass the parameters to succeeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These values are provided to you once when you create the user. You are asked to store these carefully. They are not available programmatically as that would not be secure.

From an application perspective, you can store your IAM credentials in [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) which will allow you to obtain them programmatically for your application.

Please read this page carefully: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html